# When i run the Monkey Talk i am geting no virtual machines found. How to resolve this?

Tags: android

I am a Test Engineeer. I am new to Monkey Talk. I have downloaded the Monkey Talk from the site and extracted the zip file.

I ran the MonkeyTalk IDE. I am getting No virtual machines found.... Javaw.exe[image]

How to resolve this?

Thanks
Chandra..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the MonkeyTalk agent on your app? If not, check this out: http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-quick-start

Comment: I installed but when i use Eclipse i did not get Android icon on the Monkeytalk or in Eclipse to start record..

Comment: did you convert the program to AspectJ? All you do with eclipse is launch the program. Once you have converted the program to AspectJ, you have to add the monkeytalk.jar file to the aspectJ path, then export the aspect j library. Once that has been launched, you have to establish a connection using the monkeytalk ide. All this is in the link I posted above. You should take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. I have only apk files. can i go ahead with that only.. i dont have the source code..

Comment: Then you won't be able to use MonkeyTalk. This document should answer you question regarding that: http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-faq

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the source code, try using Robotium. Here is a link to their page: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers

This should get you headed in the right direction. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Hii the issue is due to Path that was set up during installation of JDK. Please make sure the path set up is correct.  I got the same error while I was trying to install ANT on my system fixing environment variables would solve this issue.